# Squaring the value of an input box in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to learning React and doing a little test project each day. Today, I am trying to create an input box that when I click a Submit button, it alerts the square of a number. Nice and simple. But, I am trying to do this **without using State**. Just trying to understand how. Here is my code but something is missing. I think I am close!

Any ideas?

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  sayHi = props => {
    alert(this.props.mySentProps);
  };

  squareTheNumber = () => {
    alert('this is the squared number'+ );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.sayHi}>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder={'Enter a number to square'} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.squareTheNumber}>Submit me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you found my answer useful, click on the checkmark next to it to accept it.

Comment: The title is misleading: This is nothing to do with "squaring the value". The question is about accessing an element without using state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  sayHi = (props) => {
    alert(this.props.mySentProps);
  };

  squareTheNumber = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Should be the same as input's "name" or "id" property
    // Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements
    const { number } = event.target.elements;
    alert(`this is the squared number: ${number.value ** 2}`);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.sayHi}>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.squareTheNumber}>
            <input
              name="number"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter a number to square"
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit me</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

P.S.: `render` from `@testing-library/react` is used for testing purposes only. See docs [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/marko-testing-library/api#render). Class components have their own field with the [same](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) [name](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class).

Comment: Thanks for that. I am getting my squared number done now and able to grab that event. :)

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is no clean way to do it without state or any extensions. The best way is to use state and make things clean. But another way you can do it is to use JQuery.

For example:

You can assign the `<input>` an id, say myId. Then you do this:

```
var content = $('#myId').content;
```

And then you can change the content in the `p` by assigning it a new value.

But using JQuery kinds of defeats the purpose of React, so I would recommend using state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs to access mounted elements directly.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html